# Adding a vertical scroll bar to a JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtextarea

I'm making a simple GUI that has a JTextArea that I can paste a string in. When the string gets too long the JTextArea fills up and I can see the words going below the set bounds I have for the text area. I would like to add a vertical scroll bar to this text area.

```
public class GUI implements ActionListener {
    private static JTextArea fileContents;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();

        frame.setSize(700, 500);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(panel);

        panel.setLayout(null);

        fileContents = new JTextArea();
        fileContents.setBounds(175, 75, 275, 275);
        panel.add(fileContents);
        JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane();
        sp.add(fileContents, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        panel.add(sp);
```

I get an error when I have this setup.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: illegal component position
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.addImpl(Container.java:1111)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.add(Container.java:489)
    at harness.GUI.main(HarnessGUI.java:60)
```

Comment: Why do you add the text area to both the panel and the scroll pane?

Comment: 1) Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556). Note that not using a layout manager usually stops the scroll pane from functioning.  2) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). ..

Comment: .. 3) See [What is a stack trace, and how can I use it to debug my application errors?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3988788/418556). If you understand how a stack trace works, you'd realise that the numbers at the end are indicating line numbers in the source code. A code snippet changes the line numbers and means we cannot get best use of them. 4) @daniu makes a good point. Don't add the component separately to the scroll pane and the GUI. Any GUI component / container can have exactly one parent. It should be the scroll pane. Also, don't add things to a scroll pane but rather its viewport.

Comment: See: [How to Use Text Fields](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textfield.html). The `TextDemo` is a working example with a JTextField and JTextArea.

Comment: You are getting `IllegalArgumentException` because the following line of your code does not do what you think it does: `sp.add(fileContents, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);` Refer to method [add(Component,int)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#add-java.awt.Component-int-) in class `java.awt.Container`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This code works:

```
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();

        frame.setSize(700, 500);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        panel.setLayout(null);

        fileContents = new JTextArea();
        JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(fileContents);
        sp.setBounds(175, 75, 300, 300);
        panel.add(sp);
```

Your had 2 problems:

1. If `fileContents` added to `sp` that added to `panel`, tou needn't add `fileContents` to `panel`.
2. When using `JScrollPane`, you should add `Component`s only with the constractor `JScrollPane(Component view)` and not with the `add()` method.

Comment: You can also provide `VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS` policy in `JScrollPane` constructor. Like this `JScrollPane  sp = new JScrollPane(fileContents, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED)`